# Representation of $f(x)$ with a superposition of functions standing wave functions $g(x,t)?$

Tags: fourier-analysis, approximation-theory, wave-equation

I am trying to represent a continuous function, $f(x)$, defined on an interval of length L by a superposition of standing wave functions $g(x,t)$.

Definitions for this problem are:

$f(x)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, but can be looked at as $f(x,t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but constant with changes in $t$

$g(x,t)$ is in the same $\mathbb{R}^2$

$g(x,t) = \cos(wt + \phi)\cos\left(\dfrac{wx}{v} + \gamma\right)$

- $\phi$ and $\gamma$ are phase variables
- $w$ is a redial frequency variable
- $t$ is a time variable
- $x$ is a $1$-D spatial variable
- $v$ is a velocity constant

I have tried to use what I know about Fourier theory, but that hasn't gotten me very far. Could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

If I have made anything unclear, please let me know, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "represent by a superposition"? Do you want a sum of $g$'s that sums to $f$? If so, can we have multiple values of $w$, $v$, $\gamma$, $\phi$?

Comment: Yes,  a sum of g's that sums to f. And a revised yes to having multiple values of omega, gamma, and phi. nu is a constant. I would like to do something analogous to the fourier series.